# JMeter: How to run test from .bat file for a specific duration ignoring TG Start & End Times

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, jmeter

I have a test with 3 threads:

1. Startup
2. Actual Test
3. Cleanup

**I do not want to have to specify a Scheduler Start/End time for each Thread Group**. Instead, I want anyone to kick off the test whenever necessary from a .bat file and have it run for a duration specified in the .bat file.

My .bat file is configured as follows where I want the test to run for 30 minutes (1800 seconds):

```
@echo on
call ..\..\binaries\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\jmeter -Jduration=1800 -Jhostname=localhost -Jport=18100 -n -t "API Performance.jmx" -l performanceAPITestResults.log
```

If I run the test from the .bat file as outlined and no Scheduler set for each Thread Group, then the test only runs once and exits. (approx. 90 seconds)

In the test, if I enable the Scheduler in each TG and specify a date in the past along with a duration for each, kicking off the .bat file results in the test only being run once and ignoring the duration. If I specify a date in the future, the test hangs awaiting for the future time to begin.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**Additional Details**

In the .jmx test, I seem to have to specify the following Scheduler in each TG:

*Startup TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:00:00 
Stop Date = today @ 11:00:10 
Duration (seconds) = 10 
Startup Delay = null
```

*Test TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:00:10 
Stop Date = today @ 11:30:10 
Duration (seconds) = 1800 
Startup Delay = null
```

*Teardown TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:30:10 
Stop Date = today @ 11:30:15 
Duration (seconds) = 4 
Startup Delay = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter ignores the start time if it is past time. You can just parameterize the duration.

Just pass 3 arguments for duration like this.

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -Jsetup.duration=10 -Jtest.duration=1800 -Jtear.duration=4
```

In your test

*Startup TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:00:00 
Stop Date = today @ 11:00:10 
Duration (seconds) = ${__P(setup.duration)}
Startup Delay = null
```

*Test TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:00:10 
Stop Date = today @ 11:30:10 
Duration (seconds) = ${__P(test.duration)}
Startup Delay = null
```

*Teardown TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:30:10 
Stop Date = today @ 11:30:15 
Duration (seconds) = ${__P(tear.duration)} 
Startup Delay = null
```

---

More info on [__P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) function.

`${__P(property_name,default_value)}` - When you use like this, if the property is not passed to the test, the test will use the default value.

So, `jmeter -n -t test.jmx` will do to invoke the test.

*Startup TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:00:00 
Stop Date = today @ 11:00:10 
Duration (seconds) = ${__P(setup.duration,10)}
Startup Delay = null
```

*Test TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:00:10 
Stop Date = today @ 11:30:10 
Duration (seconds) = ${__P(test.duration,1800)}
Startup Delay = null
```

*Teardown TG*

```
Start Date = today @ 11:30:10 
Stop Date = today @ 11:30:15 
Duration (seconds) = ${__P(tear.duration,4)} 
Startup Delay = null
```

---

If you want to override the default values, you need to pass only those properties.

Ex: `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -Jtest.duration=3600 -Jtear.duration=20`

will run the setup TG for 10 seconds with the default value, test TG for 3600 seconds with the overridden value and tear TG for 20 seconds with overridden value.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't aware you could manipulate/override the __P function via the .bat file. This is exactly what I wanted and your explanation is very clear & easy to understand. Thank you again.